# Can we have a tag for MCEdit?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

There have been a lot of [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) questions relating to the popular tool [MCEdit](http://mcedit.net/about.html). Most of them can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=mcedit).

Could we create an [mcedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mcedit) tag that would (probably) be applied to these questions and available for future questions?

Comment: There is already a tag for it. [Minecraft-Mcedit]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We already had [minecraft-mcedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mcedit) (now just [mcedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mcedit)) tag.

That said, there are only three questions using this tag. It appears that in practice, the tag is often forgotten or ignored.

Feel free to edit the tag into questions that fall under the topic. Just make sure you proof read the rest of the question, I.E., make sure you don't gloss over other obvious edit opportunities.

The tag also does not have a tag wiki or summary excerpt. It might be useful for someone to suggestion/publish one to clarify it's meaning and use.

Comment: Thanks! I will start tagging questions tomorrow.

Comment: I did feel it was also important to remind asker to do an entire edit review for the changes, as to not bump 20+ questions for minor edits, if more work was needed